Access destination property from a Glue S3 DataSink
With Glue 4.0, so Python 3.10.
Assuming I am creating a datasink this way:
sink = gluecontext.getSink(path="s3://bucket/key", connection_type="s3")

How can I access the path property (or equivalent if it is split in bucket and key for instance):
path = sink.connection_options.path # Not valid

I can of course work around it, by creating my own wrapper around the sink object, but there must be a way, possibly via the _jsink object? The AWS API doc is very secretive
